# Is there more simple way to set dependency in Yii2 Asset

Tags: yii2

I have RTL layout for my [yii2](/questions/tagged/yii2) application using `airani\bootstrap\BootstrapRtlAsset`. However, I want to customize the Bootstrap using [**this online tool**](http://bootstrap-live-customizer.com/).

The tool generates a [css](/questions/tagged/css) file which I want it to be linked directly before `bootstrap-rtl.css` comes from BootstrapRtlAsset.

The only way, that I know, to do that, is creating new AssetBundle in app/assets like the following:

```
<?php

namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class ThemeAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/theme.min.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];

}
```

Then I should add it in the `$depends` of `AppAsset`:

```
public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
        'app\assets\ThemeAsset',
        'airani\bootstrap\BootstrapRtlAsset',
    ];
```

**So** is there any other way that allows me to replace `app\assets\ThemeAsset` with just the path of the css file `css/theme.min.css` without need to create new AssetBundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use registerCssFile() Concept

```
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerCssFile%28%29-detail
```

Comment: You are right. It should be used from the layout, if I want it to be applied to all views, as follows: `$this->registerCssFile('/css/theme.min.css', ['depends' => 'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset']);` where we set `depends` option to be BootstrapAsset, so it comes after it and before BootstrapRtlAsset.

Comment: @sємsєм : Exactly.. You got it... Enjoy :)

Answer (score -1):

You just need to modify the file: frontend/assets/AppAsset.php, add one line.

```
public $css = [
    'css/theme.min.css',
    ... Your other css ...
];
```

Comment: No, by this way `css/theme.min.css` will be linked after `bootstrap-rtl.css` and this will produce issues in RTL.